# Magento admin grid fail

Tags: import, grid, grid-serlization

I have developed custom import module in my Magento store. It works normally on localhost, but on a server as not expected.  I send csv data sheet using post form and on module backend it should display products of csv sheet in grid. Response status 200 Ok, but grid is not loaded completely (response html also, there is no footer, grid js scripts), for example only 35 percent of grid. See attached image:

[image]
I cant figure out this issue related to Magento or PHP/Server configuration. Anybody have some suggestion?
What does import module after uploading csv? It parses csv and stores array of product related data (attribute values, option values) in session. If I test csv data sheet with less data it works normally, fails only when count of products are more.

Comment: Sounds like memory_limit exceeded or timeout. Have a look into the php error_log.

Comment: @Fabian Blechschmidt, I am using php_value memory_limit 1024M and 
    php_value max_execution_time 480000 in .htaccess, on server and on local. Log files empty

Comment: Did you check the magento files or the php error_log? Is error_logging active for php? If the grid is not rendererd correctly a error is thrown.

Comment: Try splitting your CSV into smaller pieces before you import it.

Comment: Yes I can split and it works, but it is extra work every time split, upload

Comment: @Fabian Blechschmidt, both error logs (PHP, Magento) are clean

Comment: @mageUz Maybe it would be better if you programmatically split the CSV using Javascript before it is uploaded? If you intend for this module to run in a variety of environments (and depending on the size of your CSV files) it would be a good idea to make sure a user is actually capable of doing someone as simple as uploading a file.

Comment: Please have a look on this great debugging answer and comment back: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/217